# Using Find Replace To Update Worksheet References

Tags: excel

I have a report that I must update each week.

Throughout the report are references to another daily report of the format:

20140610_DailyReport

So each week when it comes to updating I am supposed to CTRL+H and replace 20140603_DailyReport with 20140610_DailyReport

The references are used within forumula such as:
SUMPRODUCT(
('Daily\05 May\20140610_Daily_Dashboard.xlsx'!PayDate>=C3)*
('Daily\05 May\20140610_Daily_Dashboard.xlsx'!PayDate<=C4))

But when I try find/replace now excel is opening windows explorer and for each cell where the change is made, I have to select the file in question. It's really annoying.

How can I CTRL+H to update the path of the report being referenced without having to manually select each path for each cell?

Comment: Just figured it out. Had to select "Edit Links" from the data menu. So cannot use CTRL+H for updating links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure your formulae to refer to a variable and use Ctrl+h to change that variable.

Comment: Good one never thought of that actually